# Binary search recursive function returning undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined, binary-search

Hi, I am getting undefined from the following JavaScript code. I would like a tool for debugging JavaScript, is Webstorm the best?

```
//input
var inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 66];
var searchValue = 2;
//output
var arrayLength = inputArray.length;
var arrayCurrent = inputArray;
var currentIndex = arrayLength;
function binarySearch() {
    currentIndex = Math.floor(arrayCurrent.length / 2);
    if (searchValue == arrayCurrent[currentIndex]) {
        var x=currentIndex;
        return x;
    } else if (searchValue > arrayCurrent[currentIndex]) {
        arrayCurrent = arrayCurrent.slice(currentIndex + 1);
        binarySearch();//recursive call

    } else if (searchValue < arrayCurrent[currentIndex]) {
        arrayCurrent = arrayCurrent.slice(0, currentIndex - 1);
        binarySearch();//recursive call
    }

}
var found=binarySearch();
console.log("the index of the searched value is: " + found);
```

---

```
Console output:
the index of the searched value is: undefined
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+debug+javascript

Comment: use your browser's console (try `F12`)

Comment: Arrays are objects, doing `arrayCurrent = inputArray` does not a new array make, it's still a reference to the same array

Comment: but have you heard of quality code where a little more variables make it easier to understand. how is this hurting the code really?

Comment: That depends, it's the same array so when you slice it you're also slicing the original array, and usually when someone adds another variable like that, one would assume it was done to keep the original array intact.

Comment: Did you notice you're missing 2 returns? I believe dogiordano's answer was correct, it doesn't matter if it has a return value in one case if that return value is lost from the call stack in the 2 other cases.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - true

Comment: It has one return statement, but it needs three.

Comment: recursive and iterative binary search JS implementations: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#JavaScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recursion only happens if your function calls itself. But in this case, you can just use a loop.

I found the following example on [Oliver Caldwell's blog](http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/08/searching-javascript-arrays-with-a-binary-search/) :

```js
var inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 66];
var searchValue = 6;

function binarySearch(searchValue, inputArray) {
    var minIndex = 0,
        maxIndex = inputArray.length - 1,
        currentIndex,
        currentElement;
 
    while (minIndex <= maxIndex) {
        currentIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2 | 0;
        currentElement = inputArray[currentIndex];
 
        if (currentElement < searchValue)
            minIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        else if (currentElement > searchValue)
            maxIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        else
            return currentIndex;
    }
 
    return -1;
}

var found = binarySearch(searchValue, inputArray);
console.log("The index of the searched value is: " + found);
```

Comment: And now [try that with `searchValue = 3` please](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLAsW/2/) … The slicing of the array is _wrong_, because the second parameter is the “[z]ero-based index at which to end extraction. __slice extracts up to but not including end.__” (quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), highlighting by me) – it has to be `arrayCurrent.slice(0, currentIndex)` in the second else-if branch. Fixed -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZLAsW/3/

Comment: (Not entirely your fault though, because copy&paste from the original code, where it was wrong already.)

Comment: You're right! You should post it as an answer, you should get the award. I'll delete mine then.

Comment: _“I'll delete mine then”_ – don’t you dare! :-) Your answer is correct apart from that little glitch (and that was only transferred over from the original code anyway) – the missing return of the recursive function call was the main issue here. Why not just edit that little thing into your answer (and maybe update the link to the fiddle) … and the credit is all yours ;-)

Comment: blex, you can edit your answer to include @CBroe's remark and quote him in the edit :)

Comment: Well thank you, but I did not look at the code as closely as you did, so I think you deserved it. I just noticed the return wasn't there.

Comment: wat? how is this working correctly?

var searchValue = 6; returns 2
var searchValue = 10; returns 0

You return the index of the sliced sub array.
Isnt binarySearch supposed to give back the position in the original array?

Comment: @soundyogi You are totally right, I don't know how I missed this 2 years ago! Thank you, I've changed my answer.